# EF Include sub level entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this query:

```
var mapping = await context.MAPPING_COMPANIES
    .Include(x => x.CUSTOMER_INFO)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(where => where.AMIN_COMPANY_ID == aminCompanyId);
```

Now the single `MAPPING_COMPANY` will have a single `CUSTOMER_INFO`. I also need to include two more entities of `CUSTOMER_INFO`: `MASTER_ADDRESS_TYPE` and `MASTER_CUSTOMER_STATUS`. I need these two also included or flattened with the `CUSTOMER_INFO`.

How do I do that? I have experimented with more Including statements and combining Selects and even tried out the ThenIncludeBy.EF6 nuget but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
var mapping = await context.MAPPING_COMPANIES
    .Include(x => x.CUSTOMER_INFO)
    .Include(x => x.CUSTOMER_INFO.MASTER_ADDRESS_TYPE)
    .Include(x => x.CUSTOMER_INFO.MASTER_CUSTOMER_STATUS)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(where => where.AMIN_COMPANY_ID == aminCompanyId);
```

You'll need to make sure you do not have any `Select()`, or I think `GroupBy()`, in there since Include() only works if query shape matches the entity set.